# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type Custom Request

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error but am not sure why.

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomRequest'

this.accountNumber = 4048358124;
//When I pass account number as a parameter below I get the error
this.myService.myMethod(this.accountNumber).subscribe((resp)=>{
      console.log("CustomRequest response: "+resp);
})

export interface CustomRequest{
  accountNumber: number
}

myMethod(request: CustomRequest): 
  Observable<CustomResponse> {
  return this.myProxyService.GetAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustment(request);
}
```

I don't know why it is saying that type number is not the same type as CustomRequest as they are both numbers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a mismatch in the data passed in the function.

```js
this.myService.myMethod({accountNumber:this.accountNumber}).subscribe((resp)=>{
      console.log("CustomRequest response: "+resp);
})
```

Function myMethod was expecting the param to be of type CustomRequest but you were just sending the number because of which the type check error was happening. The above code should fix your issue.

Comment: if it is working, could you approve it as answer @skydev